# Haskell Either in main

Tags: haskell, io, either, gloss

I am having trouble to use my function that returns an Either monad in my main :: IO() function.
I am able to run my code without using Either, but I now use Either to handle errors.
I have the following code:

```
parse :: Parser a -> String -> Either TypeRep a
parseFile :: String -> Either TypeRep Game

main :: IO()
main = do 
  content <- readFile "file.txt"
  let info = parseFile content
  case info of
    Left e -> error $ show e
    Right game -> let level = makeGame game
               Gloss.play ... level ...
```

So my code was able to do Gloss.play and so on if my parse-function just returned a.
How can I handle Either in the main with IO.

Comment: You should consider using `System.Exit.die` instead of `error`. The former is a well-defined `IO` action that causes the program to exit; the latter is an undefined `IO` action, and different implementations are permitted to choose different behaviors (with some constraints -- so at least you don't have to worry about nasal demons as with C).

Answer (score 2):

You're close.  In your `Right game ->` case, you want to introduce another `do`-block, so something like:

```
main :: IO()
main = do 
  content <- readFile "file.txt"
  let info = parseFile content
  case info of
    Left e -> error $ show e
    Right game -> do
      let level = makeGame game
      Gloss.play ... level ...
```